# New field in Django model doesn't show up in admin interface or model forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I've created a model in one of my apps which works fine. However, I needed to add a new field. I did this, and used `manage.py reset <appname>` to drop the tables and add them again. This process went fine - the new field appears in the database. However, I can't get the field to show up in the admin interface, nor in the custom model form I've created. Because I haven't given it a default value (and don't want to, nor should I need to) I can't use either method to add a row into the database. Any ideas?

Model snippet:

```
use_balance = models.BooleanField()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you restarted your server?

Comment: Many times! But for some reason, this time it worked. How odd... Thanks!

Comment: Would be better to know which command to call in order to flush settings instead of being restricted to reboot until maybe the new fields magically appear.

Answer (score 1):

By any chance, did you forget to update your [ModelAdmin](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) definitions?

Comment: I'm not doing anything special there:

    admin.site.register(Account)

Comment: Hmmm, this would have been my first guess, too. As soon as you start specifying fields in the ModelAdmin code you become responsible for keeping it up to date. This is why I prefer to keep the ModelAdmin directly below the models.Model, as opposed to the suggested separate admin.py file.