# Added new field to model // Admin does not reflect this

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using Django 2.1, and I modified one of my models (added one more field). I did the migrations, everything went well. I can see (in my database) that the field has been added.

Now if I open the admin interface, go to the modified table / entity, it does now show the newly added field.

What am I missing?

This question has been asked in 2011 on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077977/new-field-in-django-model-doesnt-show-up-in-admin-interface-or-model-forms), but there is no answer that would solve my problem.

Comment: What type of field did you add?

Comment: It is a `models.DateTimeField`

Comment: did you use `auto_now` or `auto_now_add` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `auto_now_add` in your field then it won't be added to your admin page.

[Link to the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield)

Comment: As mentioned in docs, you can't really change it. And if you really need to change it then probably it's not a good idea to use this option since the purpose of this option is the opposite of what you need.